# What is the chance of getting a Red Cabbage in year 1?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm trying to complete the community centre in year 1. Unfortunately, there is no way to acquire a Red Cabbage for the dye bundle until year 2.

The travelling cart is the only way to get them, and that's random. Assuming I remember to check every Friday & Sunday and always have money, what are the chances I'll see a Red Cabbage in year 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You are guaranteed to get Red Cabbage in year one if you enable the correct option.

As of [version 1.5](https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/Version_History), you can choose to enable the Advanced Option: Guarantee Year 1 Completable by clicking on its checkbox.

This ensures that the Traveling Merchant sells a Red Cabbage seed during the first year.

Answer (score 6):

- According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/85c88x/likelihood_of_buying_red_cabbage/), you have

  > **a probability of 55,5% for getting at least one Red Cabbage within a year** or 32,5% for getting Red Cabbage seeds once.

  (As mentioned in the comments, the values used only differ insignificantly from the actual values.)
- In that same thread, someone mentions using the [**Stardew Predictor**](https://mouseypounds.github.io/stardew-predictor/) to get an apparently good idea of what items you will get: using this you could see whether or not Red Cabbage will be available to you.